# Lua multiplication. Always start with the same operation

Tags: lua

Why does it always start with the same operation?

```
function next_number()
 local a = math.random(1,9)
    local b = math.random(1,9)
    local result = tostring(a) .."*".. tostring(b)
    rightValue = a*b
    multiplication = result
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lua random number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806787/lua-random-number)

Answer (score 2):

You need to seed the random number generator.

Call `math.randomseed(os.time())` once at the start of your program.